# Parent height does not contain absolutely positioned children

Tags: css, html

I want to have the "copyright" `<div>` located at the bottom of the site. When I try to put two `<div>`s (`id="div0"` and `id="copyright"`) inside a container `<div>` it doesn't work.

It's confusing for me now since I thought a `<div>` is naturally a block element, so between `div0` and `copyright` will naturally have a line-break and `copyright` will be located beside `div0`!

I don't know what have I done wrong. I only use HTML & CSS.

Here is [**my demo**](http://jsbin.com/onujiq/3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is similar to [jQueryUI slider: absolutely positioned element & parent container height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321281/css-position-absolute-container-height-problem) in that the container `id="div0"` doe not grow to contain the child elements. You can see this if you *Right Click* → *Inspect* the `<div id="dev0">` in Chrome and see `height = 0px`.

[`position:absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) takes the element *out of normal flow*, which means that it does not leave a gap where the element should *normally* be.

The copyright `<div>` is rendered at the top because the previous `<div>` has no height, since it doesn't really contain any of the images (they are all out of *normal flow*).

One (quick) way to solve this is to simply add a height to `<div id="dev0">`.

You might think that using a different position value would work as `position:relative` *does* leave a gap where the element should *normally* be. However, you cannot use this in your example as the normal position for all of the images is inline next to each other, so you would still be left with the same container height problem.

An alternative approach could be to float the 3 images left and right. This also has the same issue since floated element are also out of normal flow, however there are many CSS ways to configure a parent element to correctly contain floated children, for example the CSS [`clear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear) property.

In the following example, I have opted for `overflow:hidden` (see http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/) to make the parent correctly contain the children - [**see demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/A7qav/).

**CSS**

I also removed a lot of duplication and also opted for `visibility:hidden` and `visibility:visible` instead of altering the `z-index`.

```
body {
    background-color: #5C5C3D;
}

#main {
    position: relative;
    width: 1366px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #292929;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#leftColumn {
    float:left;
}

#rightColumn {
    float: right;
}

#leftColumn, #rightColumn {
    padding:20px 10px 0 10px;
}

#leftColumn img, #rightColumn img {
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

#img1, #img2, #img3, #img4, #img5, #img6 {
    width: 253px;
    height: 190px;
}

#imgCenter1, #imgCenter2, #imgCenter3, #imgCenter4, #imgCenter5, #imgCenter6 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 278px;
    width: 810px;
    height: 610px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#img1:hover ~ #imgCenter1, #img2:hover ~ #imgCenter2, #img3:hover ~ #imgCenter3, #img4:hover ~ #imgCenter4, #img5:hover ~ #imgCenter5, #img6:hover ~ #imgCenter6 {
    visibility: visible;
}

#copyright{
    position: relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    color:white;
    background-color: #5C5C3D;
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="leftColumn">
        <img id="img1" src="http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110205230838/pixar/images/thumb/1/1f/Pixar_Animation_Studios_2.jpg/800px-Pixar_Animation_Studios_2.jpg"/>
        <img id="img2" src="http://www.jjtoy.com/wallpaper/original/Doc_Martin___Pixar_Cars_by_GrangerDesign.jpg"/>
        <img id="img3" src="http://fc05.deviantart.net/fs49/f/2009/188/9/f/Rowdy_McQueen___Pixar_Cars_by_GrangerDesign.jpg"/>
        <img id="imgCenter1" src="http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110205230838/pixar/images/thumb/1/1f/Pixar_Animation_Studios_2.jpg/800px-Pixar_Animation_Studios_2.jpg">
        <img id="imgCenter2" src="http://www.jjtoy.com/wallpaper/original/Doc_Martin___Pixar_Cars_by_GrangerDesign.jpg">
        <img id="imgCenter3" src="http://fc05.deviantart.net/fs49/f/2009/188/9/f/Rowdy_McQueen___Pixar_Cars_by_GrangerDesign.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="rightColumn">
        <img id="img4" src="http://www.dan-dare.org/FreeFun/Images/CartoonsMoviesTV/MonstersIncForTheBirdsWallpaper800.jpg"/>
        <img id="img5" src="http://www.wallmay.net/thumbnails/detail/20120814/cartoons%20pixar%20disney%20company%20movies%20animated%20toy%20story%201600x1200%20wallpaper_www.wallmay.com_62.jpg"/>
        <img id="img6" src="http://fc09.deviantart.net/fs26/i/2008/143/3/6/Wall_E_Jr____Pixar___iBook_by_iFab.jpg"/>
        <img id="imgCenter4" src="http://www.dan-dare.org/FreeFun/Images/CartoonsMoviesTV/MonstersIncForTheBirdsWallpaper800.jpg">
        <img id="imgCenter5" src="http://www.wallmay.net/thumbnails/detail/20120814/cartoons%20pixar%20disney%20company%20movies%20animated%20toy%20story%201600x1200%20wallpaper_www.wallmay.com_62.jpg">
        <img id="imgCenter6" src="http://fc09.deviantart.net/fs26/i/2008/143/3/6/Wall_E_Jr____Pixar___iBook_by_iFab.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="copyright">
    <center>CSS 1st Homework</center>
    <center>&#169;2013 by TS7<sup>TM</sup> from NEWBIESVN Team. All rights reserved.</center>
</div>
```

Also, [`<center>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) is deprecated so I'd investigate a CSS way to center the text if you have time.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is by far the best answer I've ever received. Best wishes, mate !

Answer (score -1):

to big div. Give the Css like

```
position: relative;
height: 700px;
```

& to copyright div

```
#copyright {
position: absolute;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1000px;
border: 2px solid white;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
color: white;
background-color: #5C5C3D;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -500px;
font-size: 0.8em;
bottom: 0;
}
```

Try this. I hope it will be helpful.