# Extend height to include absolutely positioned children

Tags: javascript, css, html, wysiwyg

I'm building an html/javascript theme designer for a CMS.  Elements are positioned absolutely and can be moved/resized via the mouse, and/or contain editable text whose height may be determined by the number of lines.  However I'm running into the problem where a parent element's height does not expand to include its absolutely positioned children.

Minimal code (also on [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/JoeCoder/6csrV/6/)):

```
<style>
    div.layer { position: absolute }
    div.layer1 { width: 400px; border: 1px solid #ccc }
    div.layer2 { top: 15px; left: 100px; width: 100px; border: 1px solid blue }
</style>
<div class="layer layer1">container should expand to the bottom of the child.
    <div class="layer layer2" contentEditable>Child with<br/>editable text.</div>
</div>
```

A CSS-only solution is ideal and I'm not concerned about older browsers.  But I'm mostly looking for any way to prevent the need for javascript to run on every page using a created theme to set their height (since pages with the same theme may have different amounts of text).

There are already a few similar questions but their accepted answers (e.g. don't use absolute positioning) won't work in my case.  Unless there is a way to have multiple layers of draggable/resizable elements without them being position: absolute.

Comment: I dont know,but dont think it can be done with pure CSS.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found a pure-css solution!  In summary:

1. Set the child elements to position: relative instead of absolute.
2. Set their margin-right to be their negative width, to give them zero effective width, and make them float: left to keep them all on the same line.  This makes all of them have an origin of 0, 0.
3. Then we can set their left and margin-top properties to position them absolutely within their parents.  Note that margin-top is required instead of top because top won't push down the bottom of the parent element.

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/JoeCoder/6csrV/10/) or code below:

```
<style>
    div.layer { position: relative; float: left; }
    div.layer1 { width: 400px; border: 1px solid black }
    div.layer2 { margin-top: 20px; left: 100px; width: 100px; margin-right: -100px; border: 1px solid blue }
    div.layer3 { margin-top: 30px; left: 170px; width: 100px; margin-right: -100px; border: 1px solid red }
    div.layer4 { margin-top: 30px; left: 20px; width: 60px; margin-right: -60px; border: 1px solid green }
</style>
<div class="layer layer1" style="position: relative; display: block; width: 400px; border: 1px solid black;">
    Container
    <div class="layer layer2" contentEditable>Edit me</div>
    <div class="layer layer3">
        <div class="layer layer4" contentEditable>Edit me</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is actually brilliant. Kudos. +2 MySpace kudos for you (Or +1 SO points).

Answer (score 5):

***absolute positioned elements are removed from the flow, thus ignored by other elements***

the only way you have is to  set the child position to **position:relative**, in this way it is possible to move it using *right,left,top and bottom* and also change parent display to **display:inline-block**

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but unfortunately this fails when there are multiple children.  The second child's position is offset from the first's, which is the intended behavior of position: relative.

Answer (score 2):

If you want keep the children absolutely positioned, you can use the following script to resize the container : http://jsfiddle.net/6csrV/7/

```
var layer1 = document.getElementsByClassName('layer1'),
    i = 0, len = layer1.length, childHeight;
for(; i < len; i++) {
    childHeight = layer1[i].getElementsByClassName('layer')[0].clientHeight;
    layer1[i].style.height = childHeight + 'px';
}
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    if(e.target.className.indexOf('layer2') !== false) {
        e.target.parentNode.style.height = e.target.clientHeight + 'px';
    }
});
```

Comment: I will use a solution similar to this if I can't find anything better.  But it becomes more complex when there are dozens of elements nested in various ways.  That and I don't like running javascript on page load to fix the layout.