# How can I set a height, or allow a div to extend to the height of absolutely position elements within?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-masonry

I have a container div with absolutely positioned elements within. Those elements are all variable heights.  There are, however, a set number per row - but those rows are not defined in any way in the markup.

I am unable to amend the markup in any way as it is output from a library ([masonry.js](http://masonry.desandro.com/)).

How can I - using CSS or JavaScript (jQuery is available) - extend the height of the parent div to match that of the children?

I have a fiddle running here showing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/WZx4N/1/ - the desired effect is for the blue box to 'stretch' to the height of the red boxes.  Remember though, that the boxes will be variable heights, so I cannot simply loop through the rows and add up the heights of the first column (see the example image below).  Code for fiddle below:

**CSS**

```
.container{
    position:relative;
    background:blue;
    min-height:100px;
}
.box{
    position:absolute;
    width:75px;
    height:75px;
    margin:5px 5px;
    background:red;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div style="top:0; left:0px;" class="box"></div>
    <div style="top:0; left:85px;" class="box"></div>
    <div style="top:0; left:170px;" class="box"></div>
    <div style="top:0; left:255px;" class="box"></div>
    <div style="top:0; left:340px;" class="box"></div>
    <div style="top:85px; left:0px;" class="box"></div>
    <div style="top:85px; left:85px;" class="box"></div>
    <div style="top:85px; left:170px;" class="box"></div>
    <div style="top:85px; left:255px;" class="box"></div>
    <div style="top:85px; left:340px;" class="box"></div>
    <div style="top:170px; left:0px;" class="box"></div>
    <div style="top:170px; left:85px;" class="box"></div>
    <div style="top:170px; left:170px;" class="box"></div>
    <div style="top:170px; left:255px;" class="box"></div>
    <div style="top:170px; left:340px;" class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Looping through each row and working out the height of the highest element **will not work** as the element below it may be much shorter, thus throwing the calculation off.  Please see this example to see what I mean:

[image: block example]

Please note: the other answers to this question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947691/extend-height-to-include-absolutely-positioned-children) are not applicable due to variable heights on my child divs, and because of the lack of my need for a pure CSS solution.  As such **I do not believe this to be a duplicate question and I have already searched other similar questions.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the child elements to determine which one is the furthest from the top:

```
var height = 0;

$('.container > div').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        bottom = $this.position().top + $this.outerHeight();

    if(bottom > height) {
        height = bottom;
    }
});
```

And then set the height to the sum of the top of that child and the height of that child.

```
$('.container').height(height);
```

Comment: If each of the `.box`'s has margin on it, you may need to modify this to pass `true` to `outerHeight`.  http://jsfiddle.net/WZx4N/2/

Comment: Clever, and obvious now I've seen it. A case of trying to over complicate it on my part. Thank you :)